# If $x+y^3,x^2+y^2,x^3+y$ are all integers, are $x,y$ both integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $x,y$ be both real numbers. If $x+y^3,x^2+y^2,x^3+y$ are integers, are $x,y$ both integers?

This question begins with two real numbers while usual number theory tricks are based on the precondition that the variables are integers. Showing $x,y$ are algebraic numbers is easy by observing $x+((x^3+y)−x^3)^3$ is an integer, but how can algebraic numbers help?

Comment: A first step might be to show $x,y$ are *algebraic* numbers.  Have you tried to solve this problem?  Sharing your approach would improve your Question.

Comment: @hardmath I have no clue for solving this problem. It begins with two real numbers while usual number theory tricks are based on the precondition that the variables are integers. Showing $x,y$ are algebraic numbers is easy by observing $x+((x^3+y)-x^3)^3$ is an integer, but how can algebraic numbers help?

Comment: My thought was that if you can first show $x,y$ are *algebraic integers*, then it narrows the rest of the problem to showing $x,y$ are *rational numbers*.  In any case it would be an improvement to add the argument you outlined in your comment to the body of the Question, helping Readers to understand where you got with trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you find this problem somewhere?  If so it would be helpful to refer or link to the source.  If however you formulated the problem yourself, why do you think the proposition is true?  If you're not sure, it would be more appropriate to ask for either a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: I didn't know there were only two real numbers.

Comment: @AdamBailey Sorry I didn't know the original source. It comes from a chat group and seems like a puzzle made by someone. To be honest, I'm not sure if the proposition is really true. I have edited the question.

Comment: Put $p=x+y^3$, $q=x^2+y^2$, and $r=x^3+y$. Then the equations $p-x=(r-x^3)(q-x^2)$ and $(q-x^2)^2=(r-x^3)(p-x)$ have a common root $x$. Then the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of the reduced polynomials equals zero, that follows $p^2=q$ or  $q^9-8q^7-3sq^6+(16t+36)q^5-20sq^4+(3s^2-16t-27t^2)q^3+18stq^2+s^2q-s^3=0$, where $s=p^2+r^2$ and $t=pr$.

Comment: Also, reducing the degrees of the equation of the system for $x$, if I did no error copying, we can show that $q=0$  or $q^3=r^2$ or $(8q^4+s^2-12q^2t-2q^6+sq^3)x+q(q^4r-8pq^3+4rq^2-(3r^3-6rp^2)q-p^3-pr^2)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this solution $x$ and $y$ are not assumed to be real numbers.  I will find all $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2\setminus\Bbb Z^2$ such that $x^3+y$, $x+y^3$, and $x^2+y^2$ are integers.  The claim is that all possible $(x,y)$ are given below by $(3)$ with $|d|\ge2$, and $(4)$ for any integer $d$, and none of such solutions satisfy $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $a=x^3+y$, $b=x+y^3$, and $c=x^2+y^2$.  Observe that $x$ is a root of
$$A(t)=(t^3-a)^3-t+b$$
and $y$ is a root of 
$$B(t)=(t^3-b)^3-t+a.$$
Therefore both $x$ and $y$ are algebraic integers.

If $x=0$, or $y=0$, then it is easy to see that $x$ and $y$ are integers.  If $x= \pm y$, then $x^2=\frac{c}{2}$, so
$$a=x^3+y=\frac{c}{2}x\pm x=\frac{c\pm 2}{2}x.$$
If $c=2$, then $x^2=\frac{c}{2}=1$, so $x$ is an integer, making $y$ also an integer.  If $c=-2$, then $x^2=\frac{c}{2}=-1$ so $x=\pm i$.  Therefore we have $2$ solutions
$$(x,y)=\pm(i, i).\tag{1}$$
If $c\ne \pm2$, then $x$ is rational.  A rational algebraic integer is necessarily an integer.  Thus, $x$ and $y$ are both integers.

Suppose now that $x\ne \pm y$, $x\ne 0$, and $y\ne 0$. 
 If $a=b$, then
$$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2-1)=(x^3+y)-(x+y^3)=a-b=0.$$
Since $x\ne \pm y$, we get $x^2+xy+y^2=1$, so $$xy=1-x^2-y^2=1-c.$$
Hence $x^2$ and $y^2$ are roots of the quadratic
$$Q(t)=t^2-cx+(1-c)^2.$$
Note that $$x^3+y=x(x^2+y^2)-xy^2+y=cx-(1-c)y+y.$$
So
$$a=c(x+y).$$
If $c=0$, then $a=0$ so $b=0$.  Now, $Q(t)=t^2+1$, so $x^2,y^2=\pm i$.  Therefore
$$x,y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt2}.$$
Because $x^2+y^2=c=0$, we get $4$ solutions:
$$(x,y)=\left(e^{i\frac{k\pi}{4}},e^{-i\frac{k\pi}{4}}\right),\tag{2}$$
where $k=\pm1,\pm3$.  If $c\ne 0$, then $x+y=\frac{a}{c}$ and $xy=1-c$.  Hence the algebraic integers $x$ and $y$ are roots of 
$$P(t)=t^2-\frac{a}{c}t+(1-c).$$
Note that this means $\frac{a}{c}$ is an integer.  We write $a=cd$.  Then
$$c=x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=d^2-2(1-c)$$
so $$d^2=c+2(1-c)=2-c.$$
Hence
$$P(t)=t^2-dt+(1-c)=t^2-dt+(d^2-1).$$
The roots are
$$x,y=\frac{d\pm\sqrt{4-3d^2}}{2}.$$
Thus there are $2$ solutions
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{d\pm\sqrt{4-3d^2}}{2},\frac{d\mp\sqrt{4-3d^2}}{2}\right).\tag{3}$$
Note that if $x$ and $y$ are both real, then $d=0$ or $d=\pm1$, but this means $x$ and $y$ are integers.  Non-integer solution given by $(3)$ must come from $|d|\ge 2$.  Solutions $(2)$ can be included in $(3)$ by taking $d=\pm 2$.

If $a=-b$, then
$$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2+1)=(x^3+y)+(x+y^3)=a+b=0.$$
Because $x\ne \pm y$, we get $x^2-xy+y^2=-1$ so
$$xy=x^2+y^2+1=c+1.$$
Hence $x^2$ and $y^2$ are roots of the quadratic
$$Q(t)=t^2-cx+(c+1)^2.$$
Note that $$x^3+y=x(x^2+y^2)-xy^2+y=cx-(c+1)y+y.$$
So
$$a=c(x-y).$$
If $c=0$, then $a=0$ so $b=0$, and we are back to solutions $(2)$. If $c\ne 0$, then $x-y=\frac{a}{c}$ and $x(-y)=-(c+1)$.  Hence the algebraic integers $x$ and $-y$ are roots of 
$$P(t)=t^2-\frac{a}{c}t-(c+1).$$
Note that this means $\frac{a}{c}$ is an integer.  We write $a=cd$.  Then
$$c=x^2+y^2=(x-y)^2+2xy=d^2+2(c+1)$$
so $$d^2=c-2(c+1)=-2-c.$$
Hence
$$P(t)=t^2-dt-(c+1)=t^2-dt+(d^2+1).$$
The roots are
$$x,-y=\frac{d\pm\sqrt{-4-3d^2}}{2}.$$
Thus there are $2$ solutions
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{d\pm\sqrt{-4-3d^2}}{2},-\frac{d\mp\sqrt{-4-3d^2}}{2}\right).\tag{4}$$
None of the solutions given by $(4)$ are real.  Solutions $(1)$ can be included in $(4)$ by taking $d=0$.

Let now suppose that $x\ne \pm y$, $x\ne 0$, $y\ne 0$, and $a\ne \pm b$. 
$$a=x^3+y=(x^2+y^2)x+(1-xy)y=cx+(1-p)y$$
and
$$b=x+y^3=(1-xy)x+(x^2+y^2)y=(1-p)x+cy.$$
Since $a\ne \pm b$, $p\ne 1\pm c$.  If $p$ is an integer and $p\ne 1\pm c$, then the system above yields rational solutions $(x,y)$, which means that $x,y$ are integers.  We aim to show that $p$ is an integer.

If $c=0$, then $x^2+y^2=0$ so $y=\pm xi$.  We have
$$a=x^3+y=x^3\pm xi$$
and
$$b=x+y^3=x\mp x^3i=\mp (x^3\pm xi)i=\mp ai.$$
This can happen only when $a=b=0$, but this brings us back to solutions $(1)$.  We now suppose that $c\ne0$.

The rest uses the [other answer by Carl Schildkraut](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3649387/707186).  If $p=xy$, then we have that $p=xy$ is a root of the polynomials
$$S(t)=t(t-1)^2-k$$
and
$$T(t)=t^3+t^2-t-r$$
for some $k\in\Bbb Z$ and $r\in\Bbb Q$.  Thus $p$ is a root of
$$M(t)=\frac{T(t)-S(t)}{3}= t^2-\frac23t+\frac{k-r}{3}.$$
Note that $p$ is an algebraic integer because it is a root of $S(t)$.  Therefore $p$ is a root of a monic irreducible polynomial $R(t)\in \Bbb Z[t]$.  We must have $R(t)\mid M(t)$.  Since $M(t)\notin\Bbb{Z}[t]$, $R(t)\ne M(t)$, so $R(t)$ must be linear.  That is, $p$ is an integer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a hint (or at least some useful steps that are too long for a comment): Let $t=xy$. Note that
$$\mathbb Z\ni (x^3+y)(x+y^3)-(x^2+y^2)^2=t^3+t-2t^2=t(t-1)^2$$
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb Z
&\ni \big[(x^3+y)(x^2+y^2)-(x+y^3)\big]\big[(x+y^3)(x^2+y^2)-(x^3+y)\big]\\
&=t(t-1)^2+(x^2+y^2)^2t(t^2+t-1).
\end{align*}
Therefore $t^3+t^2-t$ is rational (since $x^2+y^2\neq 0$ or we are done). Can you finish from here?